# How to reserve internet bandwidth for .net core app

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am working on .net core application which gets realtime trades from exchange using system.net.websockets library and draw it on the chart. It works ok until something like Steam or torrent starts downloading  and it looks like I get trades with major delay. Resource monitor shows for my app around 16kb/s network usage.

And the problem is that I have similar application written on Delphi, which gets same trades, using same endpoints but it never slows down. I tried to run those two applications in parallel, during some heavy downloading and everything was tested on Win10. Also I excluded the drawing system lag by calculating simple time delta between trade time and local time before drawing, it still shows lag.

So the question is. Do I have any options to reserve some internet bandwidth for my .net-core application?

Comment: Check memory usage while downloading.  It may be a memory issue.  Is the delay only on the download and not drawing chart?  Is there anything in parallel running in your application?  The Net Library and Delphi are using different libraries for internet.  I'm trying to determine if the issue is with the Net Library or something in your app.

Comment: You could try to set a higher Priority in the Taskmanager for your application, so your app gets more resources and can download the trades faster. If that doesnt work, it's probably something else like jdweng said